# Get yesterday's content with contextual filter in views block

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a view and I try to show only yesterday's content.
I add a contextual filter "Content: Created date".
If I select "Current Date" from "Provide default value" its works perfectly.
But I select "PHP Code" its not working whatever I write. I try a lot of format.

In this [topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56433/views-date-filter-yesterday) there is a solution but its not work either;

```
return date("d", strtotime("-1 day"));
```

How can I do that?

Comment: how you use php filter code

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Content: Post date (>= -1days)
```

Instead of this

```
return date("d", strtotime("-1 day"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a contextual filter, or did you read you need one?

It can be done with a regular Views filter on the Content: Post date. (I am not sure if this requires the [date module](https://www.drupal.org/project/date)).

[image: relative date filter]

Comment: he can do using php filter read it

Comment: I know, but this is built in behavior and does not require custom php, which is usually better.

Comment: Its not working i tried. Actually the second answer in other topic (link is inside my question) works. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Obviously, 'is equal' to would require the date to be exactly 24 hours in the past. My bad, I should have selected 'Is between'. But glad you sorted this out.